# make the checkbox correspond to 5 columns only in sql

Tags: java, sql, checkbox

I have 9 checkboxes and I have limitted the selection to 5 only. The checked box will then inserted into sql. And in my sql, I have created a menu table, which has 8 columns named `Type,Budget,Day, Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4 and Pre5.(Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5 used to store checkbox value)` If there are only three checke boxes are checked, the other two column will get "0". How to do that?

**User.java**

```
int total=0; // limit the checkbox selection 
if(chckbxLei.isSelected())
{
    lei=Integer.valueOf(chckbxLei.getName());
    total++;
}
else
{
    chckbxLei.setName("0");
    lei=Integer.valueOf(chckbxLei.getName());   
}
if(chckbxAdv.isSelected())
{
    adv=Integer.valueOf(chckbxAdv.getName());
    total++;    
}
else
{
    chckbxAdv.setName("0");
    adv=Integer.valueOf(chckbxAdv.getName());   
}
if(chckbxHis.isSelected())
{
    his=Integer.valueOf(chckbxHis.getName());
    total++;
}
else{
chckbxHis.setName("0");
his=Integer.valueOf(chckbxHis.getName());   
}
if(chckbxOut.isSelected())
{
    out=Integer.valueOf(chckbxOut.getName());
    total++;
}
else{
    chckbxOut.setName("0");
    out=Integer.valueOf(chckbxOut.getName());   
}
if(chckbxFAK.isSelected())
{
    fak=Integer.valueOf(chckbxFAK.getName());
    total++;
}
else{
    chckbxFAK.setName("0");
    fak=Integer.valueOf(chckbxFAK.getName());   
}
if(chckbxSho.isSelected())
{
    sho=Integer.valueOf(chckbxSho.getName());
    total++;
}
else{
    chckbxSho.setName("0");
    sho=Integer.valueOf(chckbxSho.getName());   
}
if(chckbxMu.isSelected())
{
    mu=Integer.valueOf(chckbxMu.getName()); 
    total++;
}
else
{
    chckbxMu.setName("0");
    mu=Integer.valueOf(chckbxMu.getName()); 
}
if(chckbxEn.isSelected())
{
    en=Integer.valueOf(chckbxEn.getName()); 
    total++;
}

else{
    chckbxEn.setName("0");
    en=Integer.valueOf(chckbxEn.getName()); 
}
if(chckbxAr.isSelected())
{
    ar=Integer.valueOf(chckbxAr.getName()); 
    total++;
}

else{
    chckbxAr.setName("0");
    ar=Integer.valueOf(chckbxAr.getName()); 
}


if(total>5)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            "Please Select Only 5! ");
    return ;

}

Place place= new Place();
try {
    place.addMenu(a,b,day,lei,adv,his,out,fak,sho,mu,en,ar);// I want it only has 8 parameters! (a,b,day are fixed)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Account Succesfully Created");
```

**Place.java**

```
public void addMenu(Integer aa, Integer bb, Integer cc,  Integer dd, Integer ee, Integer ff, Integer gg, Integer hh, Integer ii,Integer jj, Integer kk, Integer ll) throws Exception{
        DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connect=db.getConnection();
        String sql="Insert into menu(Type,Budget,Day,Pre1,Pre2,Pre3,Pre4,Pre5,Pre6,Pre7,Pre8,Pre9)VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setLong(1,aa);
        ps.setLong(2,bb);
        ps.setLong(3,cc);
        ps.setLong(4,dd);
        ps.setLong(5,ee);
        ps.setLong(6,ff);
        ps.setLong(7,gg);
        ps.setLong(8,hh);
        ps.setLong(9,ii);
        ps.setLong(10,jj);
        ps.setLong(11,kk);
        ps.setLong(12,ll);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        connect.close();
        ps.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with database design. I would typically recommend a more normalized model where you might have table `menu` containing columns `(menu_id, type, day, budget)` and another table with `menu_preference` with columns `(menu_id, preference)`. This allows you to specify an unbounded amount of preferences if you should at some point need to allow six or ten preferences at the same time.

Your problem can be stated as : list values of each selected checkbox and store it to the database and pad the list with zeroes if it has less than 5 entries.

To solve this, you could actually create an `ArrayList` that you populate with the values of selected checkboxes.

```
List<Integer> preferences = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if(checkboxXXX.isSelected()) {
    preferences.add(Integer.valueof(checkboxXXX().getName());
}
...
if(preferences.size() > 5) {
   // alert
} else {
   // save
}
```

To further improve the code you could assign the threshold value 5 to a constant and extract a `appendValueifSelected(checkbox, preferences)` method.

Not to edit your `saveMenu` method. First of all it is good practice to use descriptive names for your parameters as you'll be reading your code a lot more often than writing it. No need to save keystrokes.

Before you had each checkbox as a separate parameter to the `saveMenu` method. If you use a list then you could rewrite it as

```
public void saveMenu(int type, int budget, int date, List<Integer> preferences) {
     ...
     int offset = 4; // 1 = type, 2 = budget, 3 = date, 4 = first prefence
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if(i < preferences.size()) {
            ps.setLong(i + offset, preferences.get(i));
        } else {
            ps.setLong(i + offset, 0L);
        }
     }
}
```

Again you could use a constant for the threshold value 5. Furthermore, I can't really tell why you use `setLong` while your variables are integers.

In your `saveMenu` method you should take care that database connection is closed even though there might be an error while accessing the database or saving the menu.

Comment: No problem - just keep practicing and thinking how you can do things in a more general way. It is almost always easier and faster than just doing things one by one.

Comment: Do you know where can I get the appendValueifSelected(checkbox, preferences) method?

Comment: You can write it yourself - start with `private void appendValueIfSelected(JCheckbox checkbox, List<Integer> preferences) {}` and proceed from there. It just wraps the three lines of code above so that you don't have to copy and paste it nine times.

Comment: I need to save (int type, int budget, int date) to table menu, (List<Integer> preferences) to menu_preference...the savemenu method maybe not helps